# How to load external d3pie.js file present in lib folder when creating custom widget using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, d3pie.js

I am creating a custom widget using Dojo. Now I am using d3pie.js file in my widget which is present in lib folder. In **define** function I am calling the file, and when trying to access the variable and trying to create a chart I am getting error.

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"mxui/widget/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"mxui/dom",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/dom-prop",
"dojo/dom-geometry",
"dojo/dom-class",
"dojo/dom-style",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dojo/text",
"dojo/html",
"dojo/_base/event",
"DojoSample/lib/jquery-1.11.2",
"dojo/text!DojoSample/widget/template/DojoSample.html",
"DojoSample/lib/d3",
"DojoSample/lib/d3pie"
], 
function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, dom, dojoDom, dojoProp, dojoGeometry, dojoClass, dojoStyle, dojoConstruct, dojoArray, lang, dojoText, dojoHtml, dojoEvent, _jQuery, widgetTemplate, d3, d3pie) {
}
```

And in my _updateRendering function I am trying to create d3pie chart as follows:

```
  new d3pie("pieChart", {
                    "header": {
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Lots of Programming Languages",
                            "fontSize": 24,
                            "font": "open sans"
                        },....});
```

I am getting d3pie as empty.

Comment: error message ??

Comment: @bRIMOs: "d3pie is not a constructor" is the error message I am getting

Comment: so in your code there is part where you triying to instatiate this lib !

Comment: yes I am instatiating d3pie which is the second part in the above code for generating the chart